# Why doesn't GKVoiceChat transmit any audio in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, gamekit

My game has two `UIViewControllers`. The first one finds a match with the [`matchmakerViewController(didFindMatch:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate/matchmakerViewController:didFindMatch:) method. Once the match is found, the player is taken to the second one.

The `GKVoiceChat` should be active in the second one. Though, I am currently setting it up in the first `UIViewController`. Is this the right approach? I can't find any way to do it in the second `UIViewController`, as I can't create a `GKMatch` variable wherever I want.

To add a [`GKVoiceChat`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKVoiceChat_Ref/index.html), I use the following code:

```
func matchmakerViewController(viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController!,
    didFindMatch match: GKMatch!) {

        println("I found a match.")

       // Checking if the device has a microphone   
        if !GKVoiceChat.isVoIPAllowed() {
            return
        }

       // Creation of an audio session
       var audioSession:AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
           audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: nil)
           audioSession.setActive(true, error: nil)

       // Setting up a voice channel
       let allChannel = match.voiceChatWithName("allChannel")
           allChannel.active = true
           allChannel.volume = 1.0        
           allChannel.start()

       // Redirect the player to a new UIViewController
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Universal", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as UIViewController
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

### What works

- The game successfully asks permission to use the microphone;
- The code compiles just fine. No crashes or errors occur.
- The game successfully authenticates the user, and redirect him/her to the second `UIViewController`

---

### What doesn't

- No voice is transmitted I don't hear any sounds. Why is that happening?

Comment: Probably "allChannel" is autoreleased immediately after you create it. Consider that the channel created is an autoreleased object (see documentation) and you are storing it in a allChannel variable which is local to the function so it is immediately autoreleased when the function exits. You should store it instead in a instance property or pass it to the instantiated view controller in order to keep a strong reference somewhere.

Finally, you are ignoring the error messages returned by the audioSession functions. Are you sure they didn't return an error while configuring the audio session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mention in the comments, this looks like your `allChannel` object is being deallocated at the end of the method. I'm not sure what the purpose of your second view controller is, but I'd subclass `UIViewController` and create a property that you set and then check for, .e.g:

```
class VoiceViewController: UIViewController {
    var voiceChat: GKVoiceChat?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let voiceChat = self.voiceChat {
            // Do something with your voiceChat property
        }
    }
}
```

Then, update your method to be:

```
func matchmakerViewController(viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController!,
didFindMatch match: GKMatch!) {

    println("I found a match.")

    // Checking if the device has a microphone
    if !GKVoiceChat.isVoIPAllowed() {
        return
    }

    // Creation of an audio session
    var error: NSError?
    var audioSession:AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: &error)
    if let error = error {
        // Do something with the error, such as tell the user
        return
    }

    audioSession.setActive(true, error: &error)
    if let error = error {
        // Do something with the error, such as tell the user
        return
    }

    // Setting up a voice channel
    let allChannel = match.voiceChatWithName("allChannel")
    allChannel.active = true
    allChannel.volume = 1.0
    allChannel.start()

    // Redirect the player to a new UIViewController
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Universal", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as VoiceViewController
    vc.voiceChat = allChannel
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

There's also a chance your issue is with your `AVAudioSession`, so I've also added error checking for that.

If you choose to have the voice chat managed by the view controller your original method is in, so can do:

```
var voiceChat: GKVoiceChat?

func matchmakerViewController(viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController!,
didFindMatch match: GKMatch!) {

    println("I found a match.")

    // Checking if the device has a microphone
    if !GKVoiceChat.isVoIPAllowed() {
        return
    }

    // Creation of an audio session
    var error: NSError?
    var audioSession:AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: &error)
    if let error = error {
        // Do something with the error, such as tell the user
        return
    }

    audioSession.setActive(true, error: &error)
    if let error = error {
        // Do something with the error, such as tell the user
        return
    }

    // Setting up a voice channel
    let allChannel = match.voiceChatWithName("allChannel")
    allChannel.active = true
    allChannel.volume = 1.0
    allChannel.start()
    self.voiceChannel = allChannel

    // Redirect the player to a new UIViewController
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Universal", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as UIViewController
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question! I implemented the second bunch of code in the first `UIViewController` and updated the `matchmakerViewController(didFindMatch:) ` method. However why do you put  `VoiceViewController` if the second class is a `UIViewController`? That returns an error `Use of undeclared type 'VoiceViewController'`. Thanks again!

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't know what that view controller is meant to do, so I added the `voiceChat` property to that. You could add that property to the view controller with the matchmakerViewController function in it and set that property

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The second `UIViewController` handles the game itself and makes use of `GKVoiceChat`. By the way, the documentation mentions: "In an iOS game, before you can use voice chat, your game must configure an audio session that allows for both play and recording (kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord)" so I think creating an `AVAudioSession` is necessary. Anyway, thanks again for your help.

Comment: I just found that note so I've removed my mention of it from the question. I've also update my answer an example that doesn't use a new `VoiceViewController` class

Comment: `self.voiceChannel = allChannel` returns an error: `'Home' does not have a member named 'voiceChannel'`, in which `Home` is the first `UIViewController`. I therefore removed `self` from `self.voiceChannel` and the error is: `Use of unresolved identifier 'voiceChannel'`. So I am guessing you meant `self.voiceChat = allChannel` instead of `self.voiceChannel = allChannel`? Thanks!

Comment: In my last edit I also added `var voiceChat: GKVoiceChat?` to show that you'll need to add a property called `voiceChat` to store it, which is what that the error is saying. From what you're saying this property should be added to the `Home` class